# Improve formula to accomodate newly-added columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a list of people (which can grow with time). I have occasional events, where people in this list can get points.  The points they get are based on two things:

1. 50 points for every hour they were present at the event
2. “other” fixed special rewards, which I determine manually

I currently have the list of names in the first column, and then I create two new columns for every event: one contains the number of hours present, the other the other special rewards points.  Like this:

```
|         | Hours  | Bonus  | Hours  | Bonus  | Hours  | Bonus  | Total |
|         |        | Points |        | Points |        | Points |       |
|---------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|-------|
| (Date)  | 01-Jan | 01-Jan | 05-Jan | 05-Jan | 10-Jan | 10-Jan |       |
| Person1 | 5      | 100    | 10     | 200    | 6      | 300    | 1650  |
| Person2 | 3      | 300    | 5      | 0      |        |        | 700   |
| Person3 | 8      | 0      | 5      | 0      |        |        | 650   |
| Person4 |        |        |        |        | 5      | 100    | 350   |
|         |        |        |        |        |        |        |       |
```

Person 1 was attending the event on 01-Jan for 5 hours. He also gets 100 Bonus Points at this event. His total points for that day are 5×50+100, so 350.
At the next event, on 05-Jan, he was attending for 10 hours. He also gets 200 Bonus points. His total for this day is 10×50+200 = 700.

So the formula for the total points for Person 1 for the first two events is: `B3*50+C3 + D3*50+E3` 
This formula gets longer and longer the more columns are added. 
This way requires me to change the formula for the total points per person every time I add columns for an event.  This is irritating and prone to manual mistakes.

I would like to improve upon this total-sum formula. 
Can you think of a better solution?

Comment: Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: A simple solution: move the total column to B, right after the name.  Make the formula as long as it could potentially need to be, including references to cells that don't have values yet.  The empty cells will be treated as values of zero and won't affect the total until you add columns for additional dates.  BTW, the magic to get tables like this to line up is to treat them as code; prefix each line with 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Let's sum all the even-numbered columns and multiply by 50, then add to the sum of all the odd-numbered columns. This system is agnostic to number of columns extant. I'd agree with the comment suggesting you move your total to column B, but this formula is written with your data range as given.

```
=(SUMPRODUCT(B3:G3,MOD(COLUMN(B3:G3)+1,2))*50)+SUMPRODUCT(B3:G3,MOD(COLUMN(B3:G3)+0,2))
```

[image]